# Access default keyword argument value within a decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, wrapper

I'm having trouble accessing the default keyword argument value within a decorator. If I pass in a value to the decorated function's keyword parameter, I can access the keyword argument value in the decorator just fine. Otherwise, I cannot access the keyword argument value.

Here is a working example of a decorator and a decorated function:

```py
def print_args_kwargs(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(args, kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@print_args_kwargs
def say_hi(text='hi'):
    return text
```

No dice:

```py
say_hi()

>>> (), {}
```

This works:

```py
say_hi(text="hello")

>>> (), {"text": "hello"}
```

Comment: It's possible that what you really want may be achievable with `functools.wraps`.

Comment: The default value isn't *passed* to the function; it's used *by* the function if no argument is passed. While possible to access a function's default argument values, it's not typically something you *need* to do.